# Display CMYK black using Imagick

Tags: php, imagick

I am having the issue when converting to pdf the draw layer font colour is no longer black. I have tried adding this `$image->quantizeImage(255, \Imagick::COLORSPACE_CMYK   , 0, TRUE, FALSE);` however, the quality is effected.

[image]

```
$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$canvas = new Imagick();
$draw->setFillColor("#000000");
$canvas->annotateImage($draw, $x, $y, 0,"Firstname");
$image->compositeImage($canvas,Imagick::COMPOSITE_ATOP,0, 0);

$image->setImageFormat('pdf');  
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="preview.pdf"');
echo $image->getImagesBlob();
```

***update 1***

I'm just trying to do some tests to see why the colour is incorrect. The Imagick colours appear to be inverted. For example, this code produces

`$im->newImage($imageDimensions['width'], $imageDimensions['height'], new ImagickPixel('white'));`

[image]

**Update 2**
I have discovered that the font colour becomes inverted. I do have a custom method that does inverse this. but causes the font to be off. Why does the font colour change to white. To test switch between the commented out `$img`

```
    $image = new imagick();
    $img = file_get_contents("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/7c/cb/01/7ccb010d8fddc4bcd84587ef3c34d100.jpg", false);
    //$img = file_get_contents("https://www.footballcomics.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/comic_1_page_3_bottom.jpg", false);
        
    $image->readImageBlob($img);
    $draw = new ImagickDraw();
    $canvas = new Imagick();
    $canvas->newPseudoImage(
                600,
                600,
                "canvas:none"
            );
    $draw->setFillColor("#000000");
    $draw->setFontSize( 26);
    //$draw->setFont(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . './assets/fonts/aAntiCorona.ttf');
    $canvas->annotateImage($draw, 300, 300, 0,"Firstname");
    $image->compositeImage($canvas,Imagick::COMPOSITE_ATOP,0, 0);
    
    $image->setImageFormat('pdf');  
    header('Content-type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="preview.pdf"');
    echo $image->getImagesBlob();
```

**Update 3**

I have tried adding profiles to the Imagick, believe I'm on the right track here. But still not presenting correctly

```
 $icc_cmyk = file_get_contents(plugin_dir_path( '/JapanColor2001Coated.icc');
            $canvas->profileImage('icc', $icc_cmyk);
```

**Update 4**
Running the code below will allow you to see Firstname be a different shade. Need that to match the other black text from the image.

```
$image = new imagick();
    //$img = file_get_contents("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/7c/cb/01/7ccb010d8fddc4bcd84587ef3c34d100.jpg", false);
    $img = file_get_contents("https://www.footballcomics.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/comic_1_page_3_top.tif", false);

    $image->readImageBlob($img);
    $image->setImageColorspace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_CMYK);
    $imageDimensions = $image->getImageGeometry();
    $draw = new ImagickDraw();
    //$draw->setImageColorspace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_CMYK);
    $canvas = new Imagick();
    $canvas->newPseudoImage(
                $imageDimensions['width'],
                $imageDimensions['height'],
                "canvas:none"
            );
    $canvas->setImageColorspace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_CMYK);
    $fillColor = new \ImagickPixel();    
    $fillColor->setColor('cmyk(0%,0%,0%,100%');
    $draw->setFillColor($fillColor);
    $draw->setFontSize( 26);
    //$draw->setFont(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . './assets/fonts/aAntiCorona.ttf');
    $canvas->annotateImage($draw, 45, 89, 0,"Firstname");
    $canvas->transformImageColorspace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_CMYK);
    $image->compositeImage($canvas,Imagick::COMPOSITE_ATOP,0, 0);
    
    $image->setImageFormat('pdf');  
    header('Content-type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="preview.pdf"');
    echo $image->getImagesBlob();
```

Comment: I don't know what your exact issue is, but depending on color profiles, CMYK(0,0,0,100) doesn't map to RGB(0,0,0). If you are looking at anything on screen, it is always RGB, even if the document says it is CMYK, because monitors are RGB.

Comment: Thanks, yeah it seems to produce two different colours that are 1px apart. you can very faintly see them in the picture. it's definitely something to do with imagickdraw and PDF behaviour. because `new Imagick();` displays black correctly

Comment: @ChrisHaas so ive spent most of the day going through this and learnt that CMYK(60,60,60,100) gives you rich black. I have tried adding a profile too but no luck. If the pdf is showing wrong will the print still be fine?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't give a good answer to your question. I have a lot of knowledge related to PDFs and printing, but I don't know a whole lot of imagick. However, if you have an output intent for a CMYK device, and you perform all actions in that color space, and all of your assets are in that color space, you should be fine. Have you looked at [`setImageColorspace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimagecolorspace.php)? Also, you might be able to create the image in CMYK, and then export it to RGB, changing the color space to something like sRGB

Comment: If you want a PDF, why not use a PDF library (e.g. FPDF), put the image as the background and the text over it? That way the font color would be defined as RGB, not CMYK. Moreover you would get a better quality for the text because PDF fonts are vector-based.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need, and shouldn't set the canvas image to CMYK before compositing it.

I actually don't know what is happening under the hood, but I think what is happening is that attempting to convert an RGB image that contains transparency to CMYK is a silly thing to do, and so instead of 'converting' it, ImageMagick assumes you just want to treat that canvas image as CMYK already, and so the colours get mapped (but not transformed) from RGBA to CMYK.

However, ImageMagick is understands that compositing images that contain transparency onto a CMYK image is a sensible thing to do, and so it supports composting RGBA images onto CMYK and doing the appropriate conversion at the same time.

Anyway, regardless of what is actually happening internally, this code appears to work:

```
<?php

$image = new Imagick();
$img = file_get_contents("second.tif", false);

$image->readImageBlob($img);

$imageDimensions = $image->getImageGeometry();
$draw = new ImagickDraw();

$canvas = new Imagick();
$canvas->newPseudoImage(
    $imageDimensions['width'],
    $imageDimensions['height'],
    "canvas:none"
);

$fillColor = new \ImagickPixel();
$fillColor->setColor('black');
$draw->setFillColor($fillColor);
$draw->setFontSize( 26);

$canvas->annotateImage($draw, 45, 89, 0,"Firstname");
$canvas->transformImageColorspace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_CMYK);
$image->compositeImage($canvas,Imagick::COMPOSITE_ATOP,0, 0);

$image->setImageFormat('pdf');
$image->writeImages(__DIR__ . "working.pdf", false);
```

Comment: Typo found in `setColor()` line. Missing `)`. Also, the percentage should be omitted according to the [official documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagickpixel.setcolor.php)

Comment: thanks, actually black is probably more appropriate seeing as it's an RGB image.